# SBT plugin for Intellij IDEA Build #IC-181

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I downloaded Intellij IDEA Build #IC-181. When I want to import my SBT project, I do not find such option.
[image]

How can I add SBT support?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not install the Scala Plugin!

If you updated to Intellij - make sure that you also updated the Plugins.

If you have, you just can open a directory that contains a `build.sbt` and Intellij will automatically recognize it.